# Invest in this word and it'll never leave

Tags: word, wordplay

Title gives the base word, the rest of these are plays on or around that word.

> Add my first, and you'll turn me into an agent.
>   
>   With you, we can jump and leap (for joy?).
>   
>   Take and shake my only one of these in order to flex, a belt, until secure.
>   
>   With an important number added on I will take control.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> Bond

Invest in this word and it'll never leave

> you invest in bonds and bonds make things stick together

Add my first, and you'll turn me into an agent.

> James Bond, secret agent

With you, we can jump and leap (for joy?).

> With you (the letter U), we create BOUND, a leap (assist from @techidiot)

Take and shake my only one of these in order to flex, a belt, until secure.

> This is a reach, but take out the O (clued by o-words "only one of"), shake it and flex it to an E,A,I to become BEND (flex), BAND (belt), and BIND (secure) (assist @Ankoganit)

With an important number added on I will take control.

> Add "age" (an important number) to form BONDAGE, a recreational activity in which one of the participants is controlling the other. (assist @Ankoganit)

Comment: 2nd is BOUND, 3rd might be BEND

Comment: Third could be BEND,BAND,BIND, 4th may be BOND+AGE